# Many pounds vs. Much pounds

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

In the sentence below, please explain why can't it be "many" but “much":

> That advice would help her lose as ____ as 20 pounds.

Isn't "pounds" a countable noun? Why does it use *much*?

Comment: Who says it can’t be _many_? Who says it must be _much_?

Comment: @J.R. both work?

Comment: I’m asking where you got the notion that _much_ is right, and _many_ is wrong. Did you read this in a weight management book or something?

Comment: @J.R. no.I was doing an English error correction，the passage is many  but I search on the internet i found the original passage using much，so i think many is wrong.

Comment: I don’t think you get what I am saying. I’m suggesting that you edit your question, and tell the community where you found this sentence, and how you came to the conclusion that one was right and the other was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work because "pound" is a *unit*.  It refers to an underlying non-count noun "weight".

The word in the blank can refer to the number of pounds (many) or the amount of weight (much) so both "many" and "much" work here.